# Table of contents gets included into table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, styles

Table of contents keeps being included into table of contents.
I use a template and it contains special styles. I'm guessing this behavior is caused by these lines.

```
    \def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      %\refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\partname~\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \normalsize\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
     \normalsize \bfseries #2\par}%
    \@endpart}
\def\@spart#1{%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \normalsize \bfseries #1\par}%
    \@endpart}
\def\@endpart{\vfil\newpage}

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne                               % совпадает с 2-105 
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%                             % совпадает с 2-105 
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%                % совпадает с 2-105 
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%                       % совпадает с 2-105 
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%       % совпадает с 2-105 
                    \else                                                      % совпадает с 2-105 
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%                      % совпадает с 2-105 
                    \fi                                                        % совпадает с 2-105  
                    \chaptermark{#1}%                                          % совпадает с 2-105 
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%            % совпадает с 2-105 
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%            % совпадает с 2-105 
                    \if@twocolumn                                              
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%                     
                    \else                                                  
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%                                   % совпадает с 2-105 
                      \@afterheading                                           % совпадает с 2-105 
                    \fi}

\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn
                   \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
                 \else
                   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
                   \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
                   \@afterheading
                 \fi}
```

But I don't know how do they work. How do I make an exception for table of contents?
[image: like this]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: you don't show what is the `\tableofcontents` code.  If it uses a starred chapter then indeed it seems near bottom of what  you show `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}` will cause what you see.  That line seems to make unnumbered chapters go to TOC file.  Try removing that line.

Comment: @user691586 This makes all other unnumbered headings disappear as well. Is there a way to add an exception for table of contents?

Comment: I use this style template https://github.com/Korogodin/NSLReport/tree/master/sty

Answer (score 1):

Your template uses a starred chapter for table of contents heading and on the other hand lets all starred chapters `\chapter*` automatically add a matching entry in the auxiliary `.toc` file.

To make this inoperative for `\tableofcontents` you can try to add yourself data to the `.toc` file.

```latex
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\iffalse}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\fi}
```

This looks like the least hacky way.